# column containing multiple specific values and create column based on the value in power bi

Tags: powerbi

In power bi i have a column which has Comments and I want to categories those comment in "good" and "Bad" category.

for eg. if comment contains ("good", "achieved", "on time", "excellent", "stable") then it should "good" else bad.

Answer (score 0):

In power query editor, in the tab add column, there is an option conditional column. using that option create a new column good or bad based on the conditions in your comments column.
There are many options in the conditional column.

1. columns name to select the column with original values.
2. operator to set exact string or middle of the string etc
3. values to set the matching value
4. output you want if condition matches.

you can use multiple if else conditions.